# non-zero exit status when attempting to install "prob" package in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to install the prob package in RStudio but am getting the following error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘prob’ had non-zero exit status
```

I also get this error for all the dependencies that it tries to download in association with the "prob" package. I was able to install the package and load the library in R, but cannot get it to download in RStudio. I've selected in RStudio the same CRAN mirror that R used (1), but still get the same error. I've also tried install.packages("prob",dependencies=TRUE). I've tried going to tools and downloading it that way, but same error again.

Any ideas? I've seen some posts on here about the issue, but haven't found an answer that works. I am a beginner in all programming languages, so this may be something rather simple that I just don't understand yet. Thank you!

Comment: You say you  an install the package in R. So I'm wondering if your RStudio setup does compilation from source by default and you don't have the proper facilities for that method. You should post a) OS and R versions, b) results of sessionInfo(), and c) the output of `.libPaths()` in with both R and RStudio.

Comment: Try quitting everything and reboot the computer and try to simply load R, `require(probs)` or `library(probs)` in rStudio. If you have installed everything where it belongs in R, it will be available to you in rStudio as well. As 42 said, .libPaths() should tell you where it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved It by installing 'make' package on my system. I use Manjaro linux. I don't know which one you use but looking for some similar may help.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30251735)